# Count number of substrings found in string

Tags: python

I've got the following function which checks to see if any of the strings in `b` is present in `a`. This works fine.

```
a = "a b c d c"
b = ["a", "c", "e"]

if any(x in a for x in b):
    print True
else:
    print False
```

I would like to modify it to tell me how many of the strings in `b` where found in `a`, which in this case is 2 - `a` and `c`. Although `c` is found twice, it shouldn't make a difference.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `any` to `sum`

```
print(sum(x in a for x in b))  # prints 2
```

Here's how it is working:

```
>>> [x in a for x in b]
[True, True, False]
>>> t = [x in a for x in b]
>>> sum(t)  # sum() is summing the True values here
2
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `sum(map(lambda x: 1 if x in a else 0, b))` or `sum([1 if x in a else 0 for x in b])`

Answer (score 0):

this will do what you want:

```
def anycount(it):
    return len([e for e in it if e])

a = "a b c d c"
b = ["a", "c", "e"]

print (anycount(x in a for x in b))
2
```

Comment: `Something like` is always a very bad start for a answer. If you are not 100% sure about your answer, consider to put it as an comment. If you can't comment, wait until you earned the needed reputation to prevent being downvoted.

Comment: If you think that the answer is wrong then you should downvote. I'm not concerned about people who downvote on style. Thank you for the advice.